# Building a Form that allows the Browser to Prepopulate with the Username/Email & Password

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, forms, google-chrome

Users are complaining about my site, saying that they Sign In form is "not allowing the Firefox and Chrome browsers to "remember password".  You should allow people to remember the password in their browser--it will come in handy in the future on future visits."

Any ideas why this would be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed.  There is a non-standard, but recognized [autocomplete attribute](https://wiki.mozilla.org/The_autocomplete_attribute_and_web_documents_using_XHTML) that can be applied to form elements.

Check in your HTML for something like this:

```
<input type="password" name="the-password" id="the-password" autocomplete="off"/>
```

It can also be set by Javascript:

```
var thePassword = document.getElementById('the-password');
thePassword.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
```